# Importing modules in Illustrator JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, require, adobe-illustrator

I’ve written a JavaScript for Adobe Illustrator to automatically add text labels to shapes. The problem is that the shapes have sometimes odd forms (like U f.e.) it’s therefore hard to find the visual center of the shapes lying inside the shape to place the text label. I found the following algorithm:

https://blog.mapbox.com/a-new-algorithm-for-finding-a-visual-center-of-a-polygon-7c77e6492fbc

which would probably do the job so I tried to use it in my Illustrator JavaScript.
I’m not experienced in writing JavaScript. The problem is that using this algo I need to import a module called ‘tinyqueue’ by adding following line (line 3 of file polylabel.js in above link):

```
var Queue = require('tinyqueue');
```

When trying to run my script I get the following Illustrator error message:

```
Error 24: require is not a function. Line: 3 -> var Queue = require('tinyqueue');
```

I wonder if it’s possible in Illustrator JavaScript to import the ‘tinyqueue’ module? If yes : could you please instruct me in how to do it?
Many thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Do you have `node.js` installed?

Comment: Hi Ozgur, thank you for your reply! 
I installed node.js ( https://nodejs.org ) as you suggested on my Windows 10 PC, using the Windows install Wizard for Node.js (including the dependencies). I have not run any additional commands so far on installed files. As mentioned, I’m quite new to JavaScript. I guess I now have to include a .js file from the node.js install directories in top of my Illustrator .js script? like f.e.:
#include ' C:/Program Files/nodejs/node_modules/npm/<some_file.js>’
Can you please instruct me in how to use node.js in Illustrator scripts? Kind regards!

Comment: Hi Hozzi, using your command prompt navigate to the folder that your project resides. Type `npm init -y` and hit enter. It will create a package.json file. Then type `npm install tinyqueue` and hit enter. It will download and install all files necessary. You can then use `var Queue = require('tinyqueue');` in your code

Comment: Hi Hi Ozgur, thank you for your reply! I've been able to execute my script using node.js. FYI: It looks like 'require' and external modules are not supported for Adobe Illustrator JavaScript (ES3 style), at least that is what Adobe fellows told me, see https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/require-keyword-to-import-modules-in-illustrator-javascript/m-p/11721128?page=1&profile.language=fr#M257764

Comment: Hi hozzi.fozzi, I'm glad that you resolved this issue